# Is there any way to specify periods with cron without setting up multiple instances?

Tags: cron

I want a cron job to run between 7 AM and 10 PM, every day, at 5 minute intervals. Normally this would be okay if it was 5 minute intervals, because you could just use "/5", but is there a way to specify it as 5 minute intervals but skip the times between 10PM and 7AM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minutes are specified separately from the hours in `crontab`. Specify minutes using the periodic notation, and the hours as a range.

```
*/5 7-21 * * * /path/to/script
```

Answer (score 1):

Below would help for Quartz scheduler

```
0 00/5 7-21 * * ?
```